# How Data Binding and Observable pattern works in Android?

Tags: android, data-binding, observable

I am learning Data Binding in Android , and I am little bit confused how exactly Observable pattern works.

I have one example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    activityMainBinding.setStudent(new Student("Rahul"));
    activityMainBinding.executePendingBindings();
}
}
```

And

```
public class Student extends BaseObservable {

private String  name;

public Student(String rahul) {
    name = rahul;
}

@Bindable
public String getName() {      
    return this.name;
}


public void setName(String name) {        
    this.name = name;
   notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name);
}
}
```

xml style:

```
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="student"
        type="example.com.password.Student"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="example.com.password.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@={student.name}"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{student.name}"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textViewa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have some questions about workflow here:

How TextView exactly knows when is Student.name changed ?

What  @Binding annotation on getter method and notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name) in setter method do ?

Answer (score 0):

> How TextView exactly knows when is Student.name changed ?
>
> What @Binding annotation on getter method and
>   notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name) in setter method do ?

For every method annotated with `@Bindable` annotation, a BR(Binding Resource, Data Binding equivalent of `R.java`) field with the method name is generated remove get prefix (here `BR.name`).

On calling `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.name)`, databinding invalidates the usages of the mapped method (here `getName()`) and the method is called to fetch new data and the new value is updated in textView.